# Errors when compiling a java program with maven on windows

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm attempting to compile [javabot](http://github.com/evanchooly/javabot) on windows using maven 2. I've compiled java programs in the past ( so I know the default JDK is working correctly), and this is my first time using maven. The error I'm getting is:

> [INFO] Compilation failure
>
> \evanchooly-javabot-dbea131\apt-tools\src\main\java\javabot\maven\Indexer.java:[23,37]
> package com.sun.tools.javac.processing
> does not exist error: Bad service
> configuration file, or exception
> thrown while constructing Processor
> object:
> javax.annotation.processing.Processor:
> Provider javabot.maven.Indexer not
> found

I (think) I've correctly set all the environment variables correctly, as directed to on the maven download page, as well as having upgraded to Java 1.6.0_22, and still the same errors.

I've contacted other people, who've told me that maven is able to compile the program correctly on OSX and Linux without any problems. Could someone give me clear instructions of what would need to be done to compile javabot on windows using maven? Thanks.
(I'm running windows XP, 32 bit)

Comment: Just to make sure that maven's java.home is correctly looking at your 1.6 jdk, can you create a property like <my.java.home>${java.home}</my.java.home> then run help:effective-pom and see what my.java.home evaluates to.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4825107

Answer (score 3):

> I've contacted other people, who've told me that maven is able to compile the program correctly on OSX and Linux without any problems. Could someone give me clear instructions of what would need to be done to compile javabot on windows using maven? Thanks. (I'm running windows XP, 32 bit)

Well, the project is in such a state that the above doesn't have any value, it's just impossible to build the current head version out of the box (missing module, missing dependencies, etc).

Anyway, try to add the following to the `pom.xml` of the `apt-tools` module:

```
<profile>
  <id>tools</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>java.vendor</name>
      <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Obviously, this is not tested.

Comment: I tried this solution, with unfortunately, no success. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @maslen: What error do you get with the above? Exactly the same one??

Answer (score 0):

com.sun.tools is an internal sun package. You are NOT supposed to code to them, as they can change at any time. For reference see : http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html

The fact that your code broke, means that sun(oracle) did change the class that the tools were built against.

You have 2 ways to fix this.

1) Change the code to not rely on com.sun

2) Randomly change JDK versions until you find one that will compile it.